# How to write special characters in Android

Tags: android

I want to add units to my `TextView`, such as power (^2, like small letter above the line of text), micro symbol (µ), etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: µ can be wrriten in UTF-8 format as MICRO SIGN (U+00B5)

Comment: Check [this](http://android-expert.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-do-i-insert-special-characters-as.html)

Comment: @Dhruti: Thank you, it's exactly what I need + good example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can use Unicode characters for your `Textview`

```
TextView tvtext = new TextView(this);
tvText.setText("unicode characters \u00B5");
```

you can find Unicode for all characters

http://unicode-table.com/en/

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this in your strings.xml

```
&#956;

HTML Entity (decimal)   &#956;
C/C++/Java source code  "\u03BC"
```

Link: [URL reference](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03BC/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
u00B5 - for  micro - µ

u00B2 - for square (x²)
```

Please refer [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160719160206/http://android-expert.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-do-i-insert-special-characters-as.html) for more symbols to use in android application.