# Some Font Characters Doesn't Seem Properly On Android?

Tags: android, android-fonts

For Android and IOS platforms same font used. It's looking good on IOS, but android doesn't show some characters like "**Ş**", "**Ğ**" properly.The below screenshot from android.

[image]

Seems it's not font specific problem beacuse on IOS working well.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/avenirltstd_book"
    android:text="Şikayet Grafiği"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dp18" />
```

Is there any special way to show these characters with same font? Or the solution is to stop dealing with this and use different font ?

Answer (score 0):

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592013/unicode-string-in-xml) for setting special characters in xml file and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637637/how-to-write-special-characters-in-android) if you want to set using java language

Comment: Unfortunately, these links didn't help.  If the problem was to not see those characters  anyway then it'd be okay.